# ASP.NET и чтение данных из файла

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Совсем недавно стал работать с ASP.NET. Итак у меня есть сайт MVC(мало отличающийся от первоначального шаблона). Я хочу, чтобы при открытии страницы Home/About у меня выводился текст из файла...
Ну и дальше наверное понимаете: я наивно стал использовать StreamReader. В итоге наш вылез "любимый" `FileNotFoundException`. Я уже пробовал разные варианты: вставить код в cshtml с помощью Razor, поместить код в `HomeController.cs`.
Вообщем, просьба объяснить почему не работает `StreamReader`, почему не находит файл и как это исправить...
Ах да! Я не знаю полный путь)

```
string text;
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("TextFile1.txt")
text = sr.ReadLine();
ViewBag.Message = text;
```

P.S Файл помещал в папку с кодом и  в папку самого проекта

Comment: Абсолютный путь пробовали задавать?

Comment: потому что указывать  надо полный путь к файлу, а не просто имя. При указании имени сервер будет искать его в текущее директории, рабочей директории и так далее по порядку.

Comment: в папку `bin` его закиньте, и будет вам скорее всего счастье,но логичнее в `bin\add_data`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string appDataPath = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"~/App_Data");
string fileName = "TextFile1.txt";
string absolutePathToFile = Path.Combine(appDataPath, fileName);

StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(absolutePathToFile) ;
...
```

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7600118/using-server-mappath-in-mvc3)

Comment: Все заработало! И вы дали крутой мне совет не только по ASP.NET

Answer (score 1):

Надеюсь это вам поможет

Read Data From XML in ASP.Net MVC 5
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/xiankaylle/read-data-from-xml-in-Asp-Net-mvc-5/

Comment: Частично вы ответили на мой предыдущий вопрос, но не ответили на этот. Можете более точно объяснить?